# Power profiles and TLP conflict

Tags: power-management, ppa, battery, tlp

I just tried installing TLP to see if it would make my laptop more efficient and it **did not**. I then removed it by running `sudo apt remove smartmontools` `sudo apt remove tlp tlp-rdw` `sudo add-apt-repository --remove  ppa:linrunner/tlp` `sudo ppa-purge ppa:linrunner/tlp` and finally `sudo apt-get update`.

So now, TLP is supposedly no longer on my system which is good, but I also no longer have access to my **Power profiles** (battery saver, normal, performance) which is quite inconvenient... They are not in the POWER section of the settings nor in the quick panel.

Would someone have an idea on how to fix this?

PS: This is my first post so sorry if the presentation does not follow the right standard.

Comment: Welocome to AskUbuntu, the presentation is fine ... `upower` is the key package providing that functionality ... So, re-install it with `sudo apt reinstall upower`  and see if that gets fixed ... As a side note, why did you remove [`smartmontools`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/smartmontools)? Did you think it's part of TLP?

Answer (score 0):

If installing TLP from the Ubuntu release-specific official repositories, then removing it afterwords shouldn't result in what you describe ... However, installing it from a none-official unsupported source like you apparently did from `ppa:linrunner/tlp` is untested and unknown whether it can cause that or not.

Always, install packages from your release-specific official Ubuntu repositories to avoid any possible issues ... Which if you don't, then you are on your own and third-party PPAs are not trusted by nature and not officially supported either.

That said, energy features rely on the key package of [`upower`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=upower) and energy profiles are provided/managed by the package [`power-profiles-daemon`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=power-profiles-daemon&searchon=names) ... Therefore you might want to re-install those first like so:

```
sudo apt reinstall upower power-profiles-daemon
```

... and there is a good chance that you'll see your energy profiles come back.