# Ubuntu 22 LTS and HP laptop - Set maximum performances even on battery

Tags: 22.04, power-management, laptop, hp, battery

My machine with ubuntu 22 lts throttle a lot and it's so slow when using the laptop only in battery.

On Windows I can easily set up a performance mode in battery obtaining full speed at the expenses of battery time.

In the options can't find a performance mode and some users said it's kinda hard to setup an increased frequence on Ubuntu.

What can I try? I'm open to investigate all the logs, and try all the mods to make the "performance" mode works in battery mode. Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Might be related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1505664